# .htaccess redirecting only pages with no subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I am using .htaccess to redirect pages from an old website to a new site. The URL structure has changed completely, but thanks to a SEO person I have a complete list of URLs I have to redirect and take care of.

My .htaccess looks like the following:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
Redirect 301 /some-guy http://www.new.domain/kontakt/
Redirect 301 /some-other-guy http://www.new.domain/kontakt/
...
Redirect 301 /de/some-page http://www.new.domain/some/subpage/
Redirect 301 /de/another/page http://www.new.domain/nice-page/
```

Of course the URLs can be even longer and contain query strings and stuff like that. The new website has a different URL structure and does not need query strings and nothing.

Now, while the first two redirects work perfectly, every redirect which contains a subfolder fails to redirect to the target location. The last URL for example redirects to

```
http://www.new.domain/de/another/page
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working now with little modifications to Anup Saunds code (and therefore using mod_rewrite).

I used the following structure which seems to work fine with all links I have and sets the status code for search engines.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^what/ever/your/path-is(.*)$ http://www.new.domain/oh-what/a-nice-path/ [R=301,nc]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Redirect 301 ^de/another/page http://www.new.domain/nice-page [L]
```

Comment: I think adding the Last flag [L] may help too, to prevent a later rule being used by accident.

Comment: This leads to an Error 500 for me.

If I remove the [L] it redirects me to the same, wrong page as before.